# What is mbstate_t and why to reset it?

Tags: c++, unicode, locale, wchar-t, wstring

Could you please explain to me what exactly is `mbstate_t`? I have read the [cppreference description](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/multibyte/mbstate_t), but I still don't understand its purpose. What I do understand is that `mbstate_t` is some static struct visible for a limited set of functions like `mbtowc()`, `wctomb()` etc., but I am still confused about how to use it. I can see in cppreference examples that this struct should be reset before calling some functions. Assume, I want to count characters in a multi-language string like this one:

```
std::string str = "Hello! Привет!";
```

Apparently, `str.size()` cannot be used in this example, because it simply returns the number of bytes in the string. But something like this does the job:

```
std::locale::global(std::locale("")); // Linux, UTF-8
std::string str = "Hello! Привет!";
std::string::size_type stringSize = str.size();
std::string::size_type nCharacters = 0;
std::string::size_type nextByte = 0;
std::string::size_type nBytesRead = 0;
std::mbtowc(nullptr, 0, 0); // What does it do, and why is it needed?
while (
    (nBytesRead = std::mbtowc(nullptr, &str[nextByte], stringSize - nextByte))
    != 0)
{
    ++nCharacters;
    nextByte += nBytesRead;
}
std::cout << nCharacters << '\n';
```

According to cppreference examples, before entering the while loop `mbstate_t` struct should be reset by calling `mbtowc()` with all arguments being zeros. What is the purpose of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The interface to `mbtowc` is kind of crazy. A historical mistake, I guess.

You are not *required* to pass it a complete string, but can pass a buffer (perhaps a network package) that ends in an incomplete multi-byte character. And then pass the rest of the character in the next call.

So `mbtowc` will have to store its current (possibly partial) conversion state between calls. Possibly as a static variable.

A call to `std::mbtowc(nullptr, 0, 0);` will clear this internal state, so its is ready for a new string.

You might want to use `mbrtowc` instead and provide a non-hidden `mbstate_t` as an extra parameter.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/mbrtowc